# Which database objects can depend on an index that would also be cascade dropped?

Tags: postgresql

Per documentation:

> DROP INDEX [ CONCURRENTLY ] [ IF EXISTS ] name [, ...] [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]

What kind of database objects could depend on an index that would also be dropped if the `CASCADE` keyword were included with `DROP INDEX`?

Comment: Constraints can depend on indices.

Comment: I don't know what else *can* depend on an index, but if you want all things that depend on a specific index see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/catalog-pg-depend.html